# Object expected in internet explorer. Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When running this code in my html, I get an object expected error and cannot get any button to function.  This is my code.

```
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$("button").click(function () {
    $("p").addClass("highlight");
})
</script>
```

The debugger say that the error starts on $("button").click(function () {

This is my entire html:

http://jsfiddle.net/J7QFy/

I cant get both buttons to change colors,  they just turn the color yellow.  This does seem to somewhat work on this fiddle site, however I cannot run this from internet explorer because I get the object expected error.  When I say run it from internet explorer, I mean open the html page file in the browser.

Thanks

Comment: add the missing semicolon after ). Is it a syntax error or a reference error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").addClass("highlight");
    })
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vx7J/

EDIT: try this

http://jsfiddle.net/J7QFy/11/

Comment: Nice fix, this is what helped me figure out my problem

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a silly question, but you have included the JQuery js file, right?

Comment: How would I include that file?  Thanks

Comment: Please post your full html file. Google how to include jQuery, if you really have not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose this code in the document ready jquery code for it run correctly as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

}
```

Comment: no he doesn't... you'll see the script is below the button. This code works fine.

Comment: No, he does not. The script seems to be located in the body after the button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other methods to bind click event?

```
$(function() {
  $("button").on({
    'click': function() {
      $("p").addClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.highlight {background-color: red;}
</style>
<button type="button" id="button">Click</button>
<p>foo!!!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("p").addClass("highlight");
        })
});
</script>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQ43j/2/